# XMLSerializer not accepting List<> type for XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute

Tags: .net, xmlserializer

I've run into a bit of a limitation with the XMLSerializer that I'm not sure if it is a 'bug', or if I'm just doing something plainly wrong that I don't understand.

I'm processing a large XSD schema through XSD2 (https://github.com/codaxy/xsd2) and enabling List based collections.  Some of these lists may have multiple types stored against them, hence the XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute usage.

What I'm seeing when using a List<> for the choice enumeration storage is the following exception:
InvalidOperationException: Type of choice identifier 'ItemsElementName' is inconsistent with type of 'Items'. Please use array of System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[...]]

I've got a reproduction here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/rc7dW6

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public enum ItemsChoiceType
{
    Type1,
    Type2
}


[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class Type1
{
    public string Type1_Field1;
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class Type2
{
    public string Type2_Field1;
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class TestItem
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Type1", typeof(Type1), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Type2", typeof(Type2), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    public List<object> items;
    
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public List<ItemsChoiceType> ItemsElementName;
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestItem));
    }
}
```

Just wondering if this is the kind of thing that I should be reporting to the .NET team, or if it's clearly not usage within the scope of the .NET library?

Comment: I believe it's a documented restriction that both the items collection and choice collection must be arrays.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlchoiceidentifierattribute?view=net-6.0#remarks): *The resulting class then uses a field to return an array of items. For each item in the array, a corresponding ItemChoiceType enumeration must also be found. The matching enumerations are contained in the array returned by the ItemsElementName field.*

Comment: But `XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute` is only required when there are multiple valid choices for the same .NET type.  In your case your types are in 1-1 correspondence with your choices so you can omit the choice array entirely, and just use a list like so: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EEnZW2